# How to remove double,single quotes from string and how to pass in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to remove all double quotes,single quotes using jQuery AJAX in  with google language translator in PHP when i change `onchange()` it does not translate the string or character if double quotes found. My code below:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="langid" id="langid<@=review_id@>" class="guest clearfix" style="width: 150px;height: 29px;" onchange='translate_text("<@=review_id@>","<@=review_title@>","<@=your_view@>","<@=neg_review@>");'>   
</select>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
function translate_text($review_id,$review_title,$your_view,$neg_review) 
{


 var sel = jQuery('#langid'+$review_id).val();
     var url=serverurl+'index.php/feedback';
        showLoadingBar();
        if(sel == 0)
        sel = 'en';



 var passDataAsStr="opcode=translate_text&positivereview="+
$your_view+"&negativereview="+$neg_review+"&title="+$review_title+"&lang="+sel;


            jQuery.ajax({


         type: "POST",
                 url: url,
                //async : false,
                data: passDataAsStr,
                success: function(response) {
                hideLoadingBar();
                // console.log(response);
                    jQuery('#btnclose'+$review_id).show();
                    jQuery('#trans_div'+$review_id).show();
                    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                    console.log(res['title']);
                    console.log(res['posrev']);
                    console.log(res['negrev']);
                    jQuery('#titleid_'+$review_id).text(res['title']);
                    jQuery('#positiveid'+$review_id).text(res['posrev']);
                    jQuery('#negativeid'+$review_id).text(res['negrev']);

                      }
              });
}
```

When I want change the language translator it does not change

Suppose `$review_title = "New "home" away from home when in village"`, it does not translate in another languages,because double quotes **"home"** at the middle of string

Any body having any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choice:

### Escape

<sub>You can escape double quotes by back slash like this:</sub>

```js
$review_title = "New \"home\" away from home when in village";
console.log($review_title);
```

### Replace

```js
$review_title = 'New "home" away from home when in village';
$review_title = $review_title.replace(/['"]+/g, "");
console.log($review_title);
```

Comment: thanks @Pedram, but can u integrated with my ajax call ?? please

Comment: @parasprajapati you should use this before ajax call, after you get title from function.

Comment: i dont know this about u can help please to ajax call where to place a .replace() function